# offset multiple rows by id postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, offset

I'm trying to update multiple rows from my query result but I can't to it.

Here is my table result

```
15347   108
15665   108
15297   108
15454   105
15850   105
15304   205
15690   205
15360   205
```

I want to offset only the first results by id_num like 15347, 15454 and 15304...

This is the sql query that i'm using

```
select id, id_num from animal where club = 78 offset 1 limit all;
```

But it offset only the first line...
And this is the result that I want

```
15665   108
15297   108
15454   105
15304   205
15690   205
```

Comment: What do you mean "offset only the first results by id"?  Please show the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I edited my question now. Can you check it out please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want the smallest value of `col1` for each `col2`?  If so, this has nothing to do with `offset`.

Your query would be something like this:

```
select a.*
from animal a
where a.club = 78 and
      a.col1 = (select min(a2.col1)
                from animal a2
                where a2.col1 = a.col1 and a2.club = a.club
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT ON ()` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col2) *
FROM animal
WHERE a.club = 78
ORDER BY id;
```